# Feasability of Spring 3.x app within Java EE 6 container - sometimes?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

Headache time..!

We have a product that consists of software with both a server and many clients. We want to replace this with a Java implementation to reduce in-house code maintenance and move atop a more modern set of technologies.

The service on the server is very SOA-oriented with lots of messages on queues, and in our minds MDBs are perfect to replace existing PHP scripts. The service on the client produces messages for the server to send and processes updates, synchronising periodically with the server. Servers are proper beasts, the clients are often customer-supplied Windows XP desktops. Now you have a little background.

We love the idea of Java EE 6. We would like the ability to build a server cluster. However, we are conscious that quite a lot of the server functionality could be handed in some cases to clients. That means shipping lots of Java EE bits to customers. My mind is slipping towards Spring Framework territory.

So, just how feasible is this sounding? Could we write our application such that we can run inside either a Spring container or an EE container? Perhaps with some wrapping up somehow?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "Spring container".  Spring is designed to work within JavaEE (i.e. servlet) containers. There is no conflict.

Comment: Spring provides an IoC container which could be used on client installations. This versus an application server on our production servers. Can we write code that doesn't care which it is running within?

Comment: The "IoC container" is designed (but not restricted) to be embedded within a JavaEE server.

Comment: I don't quite get why 'shipping lots of Java EE bits to customers' made you think about Spring Framework. Please describe what you understand as a 'Spring container' and 'EE container' - do you mean "Spring Container" like "Tomcat" and "EE container" like "Glassfish Java EE 6 Full Profile Application Server"?

Comment: My concern is really about shipping our app including a 100MB+ application server like JBoss or Glassfish. I'm under the impression that supplying our app with Tomcat (for instance) and Spring Framework would not only cut the size on the wire and disk down dramatically, but would probably reduce memory and cpu use too while potentially letting us build components not caring which container we are running within. The concensus here is to keep the customer equipment requirements down to a minimum particularly as the machines are (usually) staff desktops busy doing other office work too...

Comment: By now you´ve probably seen that your question doesn´t really fit well on SO. There are too many caveats, making potential answers highly speculative. To get a proper, valuable answer, your description should make at least a short document.

Answer (score 2):

You can either write your application compliant with Spring Framework or with Java EE specifications (EJB, Servlets, CDI, etc.). There is no *"we'll write it right now and then decide what we'll use"*.
You can (theoretically) make such decision with the application server, but not with the code you'll develop.

Spring doesn't rely so much on the application server it works in as it brings its **all dependencies with the application**, so it's just like uploading a bunch of jars into the application server - i.e. Tomcat (I guess this would be what you refer to as *"Spring container"*).

Java EE compliant solution depends on the application server services. You **don't add anything to your application** - just deploy your code (jar, war or ear) and rely on the services provided by the application server - i.e. Glassfish (and this would be what you refer to as *"EE container"*).

Fully fledged Java EE application requires Full Java EE Profile which means that you cannot run it on Tomcat (which is basically a JSP and Servlet container - a small subset of whole EE stack).

You've mentioned that you're concerned about the size of shipped application. Remember that this is on-time operation to 'ship' such environment and right now, personally, I don't think that 100 MB is something 'too large' (by the way - full version of Glassfish is 65 MB not 100+ MB and it already come with all the services you need).

If you're concerned about the CPU and memory usage - I wouldn't dare to say anything at this point without measuring it or at least finding a trusted source of performance comparison (if such exists). Measures I know are pure about startup time of few servers and you might find it [here](http://agoncal.wordpress.com/2011/10/20/o-java-ee-6-application-servers-where-art-thou/).

At the end - if you're more convinced to use Tomcat instead of one of [Java EE compliant servers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html) and at the same time, as you've said, you "love the idea of Java EE 6" than perhaps [Apache TomEE](http://openejb.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) would be interesting for you. It's basically a Tomcat but with Java EE services.

Comment: Glassfish might be 65 MB however it requires the JDK which is 80 MB, roughly 20 MB of which appears to be the JRE. JBoss does not require the JDK but ships with a compiler. So I'm really looking at 100 MB for JBoss plus 20 MB JRE then our application versus 20 MB JRE plus Tomcat (or similar) plus Spring which appears quite small but I've not counted all requirements up.

Comment: Are you restricted in any way in disk space on your customer site? Or perhaps you're concern that more disk-space taken means slower throughput? Is really the difference in environment disk-size your **most important** concern? There are a lot of other things which might be more important than the installation size. Just for sake of completeness - take a look at [Spring Download site](http://www.springsource.com/download/community). You're basically looking at 20 MB JRE + 7 MB Tomcat + 27 MB of just Spring Framework = 54 MB.

Comment: I spoke at lunch with a colleague who routinely installs our current software (Delphi & PHP) onto the equipment supplied by customers. He says the larger download or filesystem footprint isn't as much of a concern as memory consumption. We are still given 512 MB computers to install on to shared with Windows and Office, apparently requiring more (say 1-2 GB) will likely delay take-up of new customers. It's apparently not uncommon to see a machine swapping. Increasing our RAM demands may be unavoidable but limiting that increase is important.

Comment: Memory footprint is much more relevant factor. Just one last question as I've just realised something - are you going to *install the application server on the customer desktops*?

Comment: If we aren't able to ship something smaller that our app will work within, then yes. JBoss on a 512 MB WinXP receptionist's desktop doesn't sound right. If some customers may require our server components to be installed locally then Spring Framework sounds less strenuous; but if those same server components cannot be installed into our JBoss/etc production machines too, that's a headache. We could potentially write the client for Spring, the server for JBoss and insist on a proper server from the customer if they need server bits locally but that sounds like a lot for a developer to learn!

Comment: Assuming the author is a good source of accurate and up-to-date information, [this page](http://www.fransvanbuul.net/?p=68) provides a lot of clarity. If we can get the size (download, filesystem and memory footprint) of a Java EE 6 app server down to a acceptable level for a desktop, then that is clearly in my mind what we should do. Until someone changes my mind again..!